# c# Soap in xml file

Tags: c#, xml, soap

I need to create .xml files that I will store in a folder for another computer to come and pick up.  I have everything figure out except how to get the following included in the file:

```
<soap:Envelope xlmns=(I have the namespace text figured out)>
  <soap:Body>
.
.
.
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

How do I incorporate the Soap:Body and Soap:Envelope elements into the file??

Here is the code

```
  string[] source = File.ReadAllLines(sAllFileName);
  File.Delete(sAllFileName);
  //  Create message type 3
  XElement msg3 = new XElement(@"soap:Envelope",
      from str in source
      let fields = str.Split(',')
      select new XElement(@"soap:Body",
          new XElement("REPORT_INFO",
              new XElement("MESSAGE_NO", temp3),
              new XElement("MESSAGE_TYPE", "3"),
              new XElement("BATCH_NO", siDataForCSV[0]),
              new XElement("PRODUCT_DATUM",
                  new XElement("TEST_DATA",
                      new XElement("NORM_TYPE", fields[3]),
                      new XElement("SAMPLE_ID", fields[4]),
                      new XElement("RESULT_SOURCE", fields[5]),
                      new XElement("ENTERED_BY", fields[6]),
                      new XElement("REPORTED", fields[7]),
                      new XElement("RESULT", fields[8])
                      )
                  )
              )
          )
      );
```

The error message says "can't have a : in a name"

Comment: Define "incorporate". Show how you currently write the file. Also, SOAP is usually consumed over HTTP.

Comment: add, put in, make a part of.

Comment: Not in the English sense, in the programming sense. Also try to respond to the rest of my commet if you want help as your question in its current form is a bit hard to understand or answer.

Comment: Please post code that does the xml generation.

Comment: Can we see the code that is doing the Xml Generation? Also What type of object are you storying the xml document in?

Answer (score 1):

The `soap:` is a namespace prefix, but you have to handle it differently when building the `XElement` - you can't simply put "soap:element name" in there.

You can use `XNamespace` to set up the XMLNS namespace, and then prepend it to the element name.  Use `XAttribute` to set the namespace prefix.

Try this:

```
XNamespace soap = "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope";
XElement msg3 = new XElement(soap + @"Envelope",
                    new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "soap", "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"),
                      from str in source
                      let fields = str.Split(',')
                      select new XElement(soap + @"Body",
```

This will give you

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns=http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope>
  <soap:Body>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**Added**

To add an XML declaration you can switch from `XElement` to `XDocument` and use the `XDeclaration` property:

```
XNamespace soap = "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope";
XDocument msg3 = new XDocument("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
                   new XElement(soap + @"Envelope",
                      new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "soap", "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"),
                        from str in source
                        let fields = str.Split(',')
                        select new XElement(soap + @"Body",
```

This will give you an `XDocument` with an XML declaration like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

If you look at this in the debugger, you may not see the XML declaration but if you look at the `XDeclaration` property in the debugger or save it to a file (via the `Save(string fileName)` method you will.

Comment: It says <Envelope xmlns...   not <soap:Envelope...  and it says <Body> not <soap:Body>

Comment: @bnfdvn - did you put in the `new XAttribute` as I have it in my code snippet?  I don't have your LINQ query, but when I run the code on my machine it produces the correct output.  Make sure you have `new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "soap", "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope")` as the second argument to the first `new XElement` constructor.

Comment: I did miss the new XAttribute line.  wierd because I copied and pasted your code into mine.  Thanks for your help!  Lastly, I need to add a declaration as the first line of the .xml file.  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>.  Any help here would be appreciated!